# Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow. in oAuthTwitterWrapper

Tags: c#, twitter

Twitter search gives back json, but when the object is deserialized, the following error is thrown: **Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.**

I am using the following code

```
var twit = new OAuthTwitterWrapper.OAuthTwitterWrapper();
....
var json = twit.GetSearch();
var search = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Search>(json);
```

Do i have to override the Search model? Or has this something to do with twitter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anyone arriving here with the same issue as Dairo. The following is the correct fix, provided you have added the OAuthTwitterWrapper source code (and compiled) instead of the dll itself.

In the "JsonTypes" directory, modify the following files:

**User.cs**

Original

```
[JsonProperty("id")]
public int Id { get; set; }
```

Change to

```
[JsonProperty("id")]
public long Id { get; set; }
```

**Hashtag.cs**

Original

```
[JsonProperty("indices")]
public List<int> Indices { get; set; }
```

Change to

```
[JsonProperty("indices")]
public List<long> Indices { get; set; }
```